# OpenTBS Merge MS word document for labels with multiple columns and rows

Tags: php, templates, ms-word, opentbs

I'm succesfully used OpenTBS for years for creating invoices and mailings.

Now i have an customer who would like to print labels/stickers from a MS word document.
So i made a template and tryed to merge it using PHP/OpenTBS with an MS excel sheet.

But i can't get it to work, sometimes it makes an new page for every label. sometimes it shifts half the content to the next label. i have checked for empty fields, and tryed different pointers (e.g. tabel or block from OpenTBS).

the template exists of 2 columns and 4 rows.
could someone give me a hint to point me in the right direction?

attached an example: center is template, left and right are some outputs.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ms Word is made for adjust the paging in order to fit to the contents.

That is probably why it make new pages and extents some line or paragraphs.

The simplest way to limit a text in width and height, is to use Text boxes.

Simply try to insert the TBS fields into convenient and well formatted Ms Word Text box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i don't think the size is the issue.
i have examples where OpenTBS either changes the size of the labels, or doesn't see the block end at all.
i have attached an image to the question.

Comment: Your template is an ODT file, while the result is DOCX. I assume that you’ve converted the template from ODT to DOCX. What I can see is that `block=tbs:cell`  is not correct for your purpose. You’ve defined a block with several simple sections and all what is between sections will be deleted (see golden rule #3 https://www.tinybutstrong.com/support.php#goldenrules). That‘s why the table result is unstructured.
You have to merge the block with the serial mode instead (keeping `block=tbs:cell`, and delete the middle cells). See https://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=prmserial&m=result